# Using declare table to run agreggating queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to optimize aggregate query on two tables:

- UpdateHistory (<5000 rows): Id, UserId, Date, Param...
- AccessHistory (>100 000 rows): Id, UserId, TimeStamp, Value, many others...

(additional index `IX_AccessHistory_UserId_TimeStamp`:  UserId, TimeStamp, include Value, non clustered)

I'm looking for max sum value for user, counted since update date.

I've got 3 queries:

```
    declare @TmpTable table (UserId int, TmpDate Date);
                              
      insert into @TmpTable(UserId, TmpDate)                                  
      select  UserId, convert(date, max(UpdateDate)) as TmpDate
      from [ClientDatabase].[dbo].[UpdateHistory] 
      where Param = 1
      group by UserId;
    
      select top 3 tmp.UserId, sum(Value) as RESULT from @TmpTable tmp                             
      join [ClientDatabase].[dbo].[AccessHistory] a on tmp.UserId= a.UserId                              
      where TimeStamp > TmpDate                              
      group by tmp.UserId order by RESULT DESC;
```

```
    with tmp as 
      (                             
        select  UserId, convert(date, max(UpdateDate)) as TmpDate
        from [ClientDatabase].[dbo].[UpdateHistory] 
        where Param = 1
        group by UserId
      )
    
    select top 3 tmp.UserId, sum(Value) as RESULT
    from tmp                             
    join [ClientDatabase].[dbo].[AccessHistory] a on tmp.UserId= a.UserId                              
    where TimeStamp > TmpDate                              
    group by tmp.UserId
    order by RESULT DESC;
```

```
    select top 3 tmp.UserId, sum(Value) as RESULT
    from [ClientDatabase].[dbo].[AccessHistory] a
    join (
        select  UserId, convert(date, max(UpdateDate)) as TmpDate
        from [ClientDatabase].[dbo].[UpdateHistory] 
        where Param = 1
        group by UserId
    ) tmp on tmp.UserId = a.UserId
    where TimeStamp > TmpDate                              
    group by tmp.UserId
    order by RESULT DESC;
```

The differences in processing times are drastic: with 8% for the temp table (4% for insert and 4% for query), and 46% for the other two. The difference seems to mainly sit in the non clustered Index Seek on `AccessHistory` table.

Can someone explain to me this difference and suggest some fix? Or can I just leave the temp table be?

edit: uploaded execution plan on website
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BJElsysQK

Comment: Your title is pretty confusing. `DECLARE` and aggregate functions have no relation at all. A table variable variable doesn't care if you put aggregated data in it or not.

Comment: i meant I'm aggregating filled table not inserting agreggated data (although I'm doing both those things).

Comment: To understand performance issues you start by examining the execution plans. To understand those, you need to also include DDL for the objects and some indication about the distribution of values used for filtering, the number of rows accessed generally, and the number of rows returned.

Comment: Please share the query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan. Please also add table and index definitions to your question. Proper formatting helps immensely

Comment: I'd expect the table variable has a 1 row estimate (obviously wrong), so that is going to skew things pretty badly. Try timing it using `SET @starttime = SYSDATETIME() .... SELECT DATEDIFF(ms, @starttime, SYSDATETIME())`

Answer (score 0):

Indexes may be the key.

For the UpdateHistory table, an index on (Param, UserId, UpdateDate) would allow efficient calculation of TmpDate without a table scan.

For the AccessHistory table, an index on (UserId, TimeStamp, Value) would allow efficient RESULT calculation for a given UserId and TmpDate from the first part. This would especially avoid unnecessarily accessing rows where TimeStamp <= TmpDate.